# Magento 2 Add new Checkout Step with Checkout Cart Item table

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, onepage-checkout, checkout-page

Everyone! I hope you are doing well.

I need your help in Magento 2 Checkout page customization. I am writing down simple explanation so that I can get help from you guys.

Requirements:
I needed to add new Checkout Step 'Cart' which was supposed to have Checkout Cart Item table and Summary.

Implementation:
I have added a new step in the checkout page which has a 'Next' button to go to the next step which is 'Shipping'. I want to add the content below in the step.

Problem:
I need to display the checkout cart under the New Custom Step.
[image]

checkou-cart.html ->

`

```
         <!-- I want to add the cart items table here  -->

        <form data-bind="submit: navigateToNextStep" novalidate="novalidate">
            <div class="actions-toolbar">
                <div class="primary">
                    <button data-role="opc-continue" type="submit" class="button action continue primary">
                        <span><!-- ko i18n: 'Next'--><!-- /ko --></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

I have also created mixins.

Question:
**Please help me how to Add the Cart in the checkout step.**

Any way of doing this?